# My nexus screen on android studio has disappeared. and there is "nothing to show" in component tree and property

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-actionbar, rendering

My nexus screen on android studio has disappeared. and there is "nothing to show" in component tree and property. 
I was doing something in component area, and suddenly, the screen is gone.

now a rendering problem is showing

> "Exception raised during rendering: action_bar"

Comment: i found the solution, just lowered down my **API** leve from 22 to 21. all fine now :)

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer rather than a comment.